# userscript for [Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey] for URL modifier

Tags: url, redirect, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53310999/how-to-avoid-isp-ads-injection-http) with my ISP. A serious one. What I wanted to know:

- I type ***google.com*** (or any site, yea -_-) but the browser changes it to ***http//google.com*** So I want it first to change into ***https://www.google.com*** then if the protocol is not ***https*** (ofc Secure connection **fails**), I want it to change into ***http*** and reload once. (the reason of reload is below).
- How to reload one time if the page is blank (due to HTTP injection, page failed). It only need once to reload. the ***< body > < /body >*** is really blank in my case.

---

I know I can just hit ***Ctrl + R*** or ***F5*** but it still really annoys the h*ll out of me.

Comment: This sounds like a serious issue of your ISP / router / anything between your machine and the webserver you are trying to reach. For clarification: If you enter an address, the browser adds `http//` (note the missing `:`) in front of it?
What happens, if you enter `https://example.org` directly? Can you confirm this happens with any device you attach to your network (use your mobile over WLAN for example)?
As I said, this is not how it should work and I would be concerned about the integrity and confidentiality of my internet connection if I were you.

Comment: Have you tried HTTPS Everywhere for the https part? https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere

Comment: Tampermonkey can sort of half-arse this, but it's really the wrong tool for the job.  You need to write a full extension.  But it sounds like you really, really need a trusted VPN and the *HTTPS Everywhere* extension.

Comment: @DBX12 I forgot to add colon. It is the MiFi which injects http. If the server wont allow injection, the page wont load. So if I found blank, that ads didnt load as it supposed to be loaded. Ads-block is always the cause aside from that blocking from the server. Whenever I use https on secure site. it loads normally. I know it is risky, but I have no net service alternative other than that **cursed** MiFi.

Comment: @BrockAdams **Opera** Browser with its *Free* ***Built-In VPN*** does the job. But there are some **issues** with Opera. I just use Opera when accessing some region-blocked-sites. It is indeed *solve* the issue of the *blank page* I mentioned before.

Comment: If I read MiFi correctly as mobile-wifi-hotspot then you should probably reconfigure or if not possible ditch it. An **access point** which force-redirects you to **insecure http** is not what you want.